# How do i pass the Label4.Text to a new class?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 i did:

```
public static Label lbl4(Label lbl) {
    Label lbl4 = lbl;
    return lbl4;
}
```

Then in Form1 i use it as:

```
lbl4(label4);
```

Then in the new class i use it:

```
Local(webSites, Form1.lbl4);
```

In the new class the method Local should accept: List , string
The problem is to get the Label4 in form1 text.

The errors i get in the new class are:

Error   12  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Error   11  The best overloaded method match for 'GatherLinks.WebCrawler.Local(System.Collections.Generic.List, string)' has some invalid arguments

Both on the same line: Local(webSites, Form1.lbl4);

Comment: your method returns the parameter, it doesn't do anything

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Local(webSites, Form1.lbl4.Text);

Comment: @Tony that does not compile

Comment: I want to pass the TExt in label4 to the new class . Without make an instance of Form1 in the new class. If in label4 the text is "hello" i want to use the text in the new class. If i will do it public void i will need to make an instance of form1 in the new class. How can i make it static in form1 and use the text of label4 in the new class ?

Comment: Why not pass a string parameter or property to the new class? Then do `MyLabel.Text`

Comment: Millie but doing public void setLabelText i need to pass also Form1 to the new class. Its not static.

Comment: what's wrong with only passing the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `lbl4` to be a method. How is it supposed to know you want a `Label`?

A `Label` is also not a `string`.

```
Local(webSites, Form1.MyLabel.Text);
```

Also, the method `lbl4` just returns its parameter. If you want to set text:

```
public void setLabelText(string text)
{
    MyLabel.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong, and I will highlight some articles to go read

This one is on variable scope:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

This one is on class variables:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173109.aspx

This one is on static:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

This one is on Methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Long story short, your function doesn't set anything, and when you try to use it later, you are not calling it, but instead it looks like you are expecting it to be a class variable because you called it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fundamentally broken.

As for your error - you are passing `Form1.lbl4` which isn't of type string.
You should pass to `Local` method the `Text` property of the label.

Comment: At first it appeared that way, but I think lbl4 is not actually a label. It may only be method

Comment: @MillieSmith - It doesn't change the answer much :)

Comment: Yep :), I just try to point out possible oversights in answers. Mine is probably littered with them ;)